# Powershell rename multiple file names

Tags: powershell, file, file-rename

In powershell I want to rename a bunch of files with
from test_file_DAY.csv
to test_file_hello_DAY.vsn

all the files have _DAY.csv in them.  What would be the script to do this? they would be in one folder with subfolders.

Thanks

Not sure how to do this.

Comment: In short: The idiom for renaming files based on transforming the existing names via string replacements is `Get-ChildItem ... | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace 'foo', 'bar' }`. See the linked duplicate for details.